# javascript freezeing ie8

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me why does this code freeze ie8? It is supposed to generate input fields. In firefox, safari, chrome it works, but in in8 when i press generate button it freezes

```
var monthNames = [ "Ianuarie", "Februarie", "Martie", "Aprilie", "Mai", "Iunie", "Iulie", "August", "Septembrie", "Octombrie", "Noiembrie", "Decembrie" ];

function buildMonthlyEntries() {
    var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('datastart').value);
    var endDate = new Date(document.getElementById('dataend').value);
    if (startDate == "Invalid Date" || endDate == "Invalid Date") { return null; }

    var monthlyEntries = document.getElementById('monthlyEntries');
    monthlyEntries.innerHTML = "";

    // inclusiv dataend
    endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() + 1);

    // start with startDate; loop until we reach endDate
    for (var dt = startDate; 
           ! ( dt.getFullYear() == endDate.getFullYear() && dt.getMonth() == endDate.getMonth() );  
           dt.setMonth( dt.getMonth() + 1 )
    ) {
        monthlyEntries.appendChild( document.createTextNode(
                  monthNames[dt.getMonth()] + " " + String(dt.getFullYear()).substring(2)
              ) );
        var textElement = document.createElement('input');
        var textElement2 = document.createElement('input');
        var textElement3 = document.createElement('input');
        textElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        //textElement.setAttribute('name', 'entry['+ monthNames[dt.getMonth()] + + String(dt.getFullYear()).substring(2) + ']');
     textElement.setAttribute('name', 'entry[]');
        textElement2.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        textElement2.setAttribute('name', 'luna[]');
        textElement2.setAttribute('value', '' + monthNames[dt.getMonth()] + '');
        textElement3.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        textElement3.setAttribute('name', 'an[]');
        textElement3.setAttribute('value', '' + String(dt.getFullYear()) + '');
        monthlyEntries.appendChild(textElement);
        monthlyEntries.appendChild(textElement2);
        monthlyEntries.appendChild(textElement3);
        // adauga br
        // monthlyEntries.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it in IE too see where it freezes?

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with `dt.setMonth( dt.getMonth() + 1 )` having different behavior in browsers.

Comment: i tried without +1 and still it freezes

Answer (score 0):

If either of your date strings are not in the exact right format, IE8 will not return `"Invalid Date"` as you are testing.  Instead, it will return `NaN`.  You need to test for that too.  You can see this in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DxZMH/) in IE8.  You could protect against that by changing to this:

```
if (startDate == "Invalid Date" || endDate == "Invalid Date" ||
    isNaN(startDate) || isNaN(endDate)) { return null; }
```

Secondly your for loop can easily be an infinite loop:

```
// start with startDate; loop until we reach endDate
for (var dt = startDate; 
       ! ( dt.getFullYear() == endDate.getFullYear() && dt.getMonth() == endDate.getMonth() );  
       dt.setMonth( dt.getMonth() + 1 )
)
```

If `dt` is ever greater than `endDate`, then the `for` loop will never end.  A safer way of writing this would be like this:

```
// start with startDate; loop until we reach endDate
// make sure endDate is always after startDate
if (endDate < startDate) {
    var temp = endDate;
    startDate = endDate;
    endDate = temp;
}
for (var dt = startDate; 
       ! ( dt.getFullYear() == endDate.getFullYear() && dt.getMonth() == endDate.getMonth() );  
       dt.setMonth( dt.getMonth() + 1 )
)
```

Comment: @florin - See the new first paragraph I added.

Comment: you are right...so if i enter the date in this format dd-mm-yyyy in ie8 it works, but this format won`t work for other browsers.

Comment: pardon, the date format that works in ie8 is mm-dd-yyyy and in the pther browsers the format that works is yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Yes, your are correct.  IE versions before IE9 are brain-dead in this regard.  See [this article](http://dev.enekoalonso.com/2010/09/21/date-from-iso-8601-string/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just do <= instead of the negated strict ==.